# Cross link of Hong Kong passports

Tags: visas, usa, passports, canada, hong-kong-citizens

I am now holding a Hong Kong passport, with a US and a Canadian visa on it. I wish to renew my passport now, do I **have** to cross link the old one with the new one, in order that the visas are still valid?

Sorry if this question is too specific.

Comment: What does "cross link" mean here?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I think the OP means if he is *required* to file a transfer of conditions at the respective issuing posts.  There is possibly something in the Geneva Conventions about this, but cannot immediately locate it.

Answer (score 1):

No. See [13.18](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/manuals/enf/enf04-eng.pdf) for Canada - much the same applies for [USA](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/826/~/what-to-do-if-my-visa-is-in-an-expired-passport).